# Array of pointers to find sizeof string

Tags: c

Suppose we have the scenario..

```
char *a[] = {"abcd","cdef"};
```

I want to know the sizeof of string "abcd", I dont want to use `strlen`.

Please answer me how to get sizeof of the string "abcd"?

Comment: I'm afraid you need `strlen`. Is there any reason you can't use `strlen` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Why use strlen when the sizes are known at compile time? That's just useless processing to get a value which you already know.

Comment: @Lundin correct, but without using the quirks of your (BTW good) answer youn can't.

Comment: char *a[] = {"ab\0cd","cdef"}; in this case i want sizeof string "ab\0cd" as 5 so i cant use strlen @MichaelWalz

Comment: @Ravindrakanmus Check my Answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `"abcd"` is compile-time known  array of type `char[5]` and it is written directly into source code, you could just use:

```
sizeof("abcd")
```

Notice, that:

```
sizeof("abcd") == strlen("abcd") + 1
```

as the former includes terminating `NUL` character.

Comment: char *a[] = {"ab\0cd","cdef"}; in this case i want sizeof string "ab\0cd" as 5 so i cant use strlen @Grzegorz

Comment: But you can use `sizeof()`. @Grzegorz Szpetkowski mention `strlen()` to highlight how its result would differ from `sizeof()`. because `"abcd"` = `{'a','b','c','d','\0'}`, strlen will return 4, and sizeof will return 5. Also, `"ab\0cd"` = `{'a','b','\0','c','d','\0'}`, and strlen will return 2 whereas sizeof will return 6

Comment: @Sigve..Yeah you are right..for "ab\0cd" sizeof will return 6..But my question how to trace with this declarartion char *a[] = {"ab\0cd","bb\0cd\0hh"};

Comment: @Ravindrakanmus You just messed up the whole Answers by doing that, please Ask a new Question. I already give you the Answer.

Comment: @Michi Its my declaration char *a[] = {"ab\0cd\0hh","hgad"}; I want length of this string "ab\0cd\0hh" as 8..how should i get it?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over `a[0]` untill `\0` is found.

i.e. `a[0][0], a[0][1], a[0][2], ....`

But, as people say, what is the need to re-invent the wheel. It is better to use `strlen()`.

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for a way that doesn't use strlen. There may be plenty of reasons why, execution speed is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Put the actual string constants as separate declarations:

```
const char STR1[] = "abcd";
const char STR2[] = "cdef";
```

Then either build up a couple of corresponding tables:

```
const char* STR_TABLE [] = 
{
  STR1,
  STR2
};

const size_t STR_SIZES [] =
{
  sizeof(STR1),
  sizeof(STR2)
};
```

Or alternatively, use a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  const char*  str;
  size_t       size;
} str_t;

const str_t STR_TABLE [] = 
{
  { STR1, sizeof(STR1) },
  { STR1, sizeof(STR2) },
};
```

It should be noted that the size of a character array is not the same as the string length, because string length doesn't take the nul termination in account, which `sizeof` does. To get the string length out of the above example, at compile-time, use `sizeof(STR1)-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int size(char *ptr){
    int offset = 0;
    int len = 0;

    while (*(ptr + offset) != '\0'){
        ++len;
        ++offset;
    }

    return len;
}

int main(void){
    char *a[] = {"abcd","cdef"};

    int len = size(a[0]);
    printf("The size of\t%s\tis\t%d\n",a[0], len);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> The size of abcd    is  4

Comment: char *a[] = {"ab\0cd","cdef"}; in this case i want sizeof string "ab\0cd" as 5 so i cant use strlen @Michi

Comment: @Ravindrakanmus, my answer did what you asked, now you come with something else, Why ? you just terminated your string when you added \0.

Comment: Yeah actually i want like this only..so please let me know if you know the logic for this..

Comment: @Ravindrakanmus You just messed up the whole Answers by doing that, please Ask a new Question. I already give you the Answer.